# Remove rows with more than one hyphen in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if it's possible to remove the row with more than one hyphens - like two hyphens but keep the rows with one hyphen.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'apple_pie': ["Hong Kong - London - New York", "Fuji Apple - Best apple pie"],
    'shipped_date': ["2021-09-23 21:24:06", "2021-09-25 11:24:06"]
}) 


                       apple_pie         shipped_date
0  Hong Kong - London - New York  2021-09-23 21:24:06
1    Fuji Apple - Best apple pie  2021-09-25 11:24:06
```

Expected output

```
                       apple_pie         shipped_date
1    Fuji Apple - Best apple pie  2021-09-25 11:24:06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need filter one or zero `hyphens` use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html):

```
df[df['apple_pie'].str.count('-').le(1)]
```

Or is possible also add spaces:

```
df[df['apple_pie'].str.count(' - ').le(1)]
```